# EF1: Filtering derived types of entity class using .OfType<> by passing a string value

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-hierarchy, table-per-type

I have a situation where I'm trying to filter a LINQ select using a derived sub class.

`ctx.BaseEntity.OfType<SubClass>()` - this works fine.

However I'd like to do this using a string value instead. I've come across a performance barrier when I have lots (>20) Sub Classes and selecting an Entity without using OfType just isn't an option. I have a generic UI that renders from the base class, so I don't know what Class Type will be returned at compile time.

So what I'd like to do is this:

1. Perform a projected Select where I
   return just the SubClassType from
   the database
2. Perform a second select
   using this value as the OfType to
   only select the relevant related
   entity from the database (No mass
   unions generated)

   ```
       int id = 1;
       var classType = (from c in ctx.BaseClass.Include("ClassType")
                                  where c.id == id
                                  select new
                                             {
                                                 c.ClassType.TypeName
                                             }).First();

       BaseClass caseQuery = ctx.BaseClass.OfType<classType.TypeName>()
                       .Include("ClassType")
                       .Include("ChildEntity1")
                       .Include("ChildEntity2")
                       .Where(x => x.id== id);
   ```

But obviously this won't work because OfType requires a Type and not a string.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

**Update:**
As a side note to the original question, it turns out that the moment you project a query that uses a Navigation Property - it builds the monster SQL too, so I've ended up using a stored procedure to populate my ClassType entity from the BaseClass Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've just got it to work using eSQL, which I'd never used before. I've posted the code here just in case it helps someone. Has anyone else got a more strongly typed solution they can think of?

```
BaseClass caseQuery = ctx.BaseClass.CreateQuery<BaseClass>("SELECT VALUE c FROM OFTYPE(Entities.[BaseClass],namespace.[" + classType.TypeName + "])  as c")
                .Include("ClassType")
                .Include("ChildEntity1")
                .Include("ChildEntity2")
                .Where(x => x.id== id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the headline question about calling `OfType` with a string / runtime type, you can do the following:

```
// Get the type, assuming the derived type is defined in the same assembly 
// as the base class and you have the type name as a string
var typeToFilter = typeof(BaseClass)
     .Assembly
     .GetType("Namespace." + derivedTypeName);

// The use reflection to get the OfType method and call it directly
MethodInfo ofType = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("OfType");
MethodInfo ofTypeGeneric = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeToFilter });
var result = (IQueryable<Equipment>)generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { equipment });
```

Combine this with your stored procedure to get the class name and you (should?) avoid the massive join - I don't have table-per-type implementation to play with so I can't test.